# Address Normalization output to CSV Python

Tags: python, csv

Hi everyone so I am running an address normalization process and saving the output to a csv. The output of my normalization process has multiple columns. Can anyone help me save the output of my process into a CSV?

```
import json
import pprint
import urllib
import csv

with open ('C:/Users/users/Desktop/TEST.csv', 'rb') as csvinput:
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        query = ' '.join(str(x) for x in (row[0], row[1], row[3]))
        normalized = query.replace(" ", "+")
        BaseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/verify?country=PHL&freeform='
        URL = BaseURL + normalized
        response = urllib.urlopen(URL).read()
```

The output of the normalizer is both varied and large. Any tips on how i can go about it? Can anyone provide a script on how i can go about it?

Comment: you seem to know `csv.reader`. Use `csv.writer` to store your information as csv.

Comment: Where do you get your data from? Maybe it is more efficient to do the whole data handling when retrieving the data. Do you want to create a new csv-file or do you want to add the new data to the input-file?

Comment: @albert data is my own and i wanted to create a csv of the output of my normalizer.Yes I wanted to add the new data to the input file